# OpenSSL compile error: 'ENGINE' redeclared as different kind of symbol

Tags: c, openssl

I have to compile some legacy C code along with OpenSSL on linux system.
I already ran make on OpenSSL and it looks quite well.

Then I started to include OpenSSL's CMAC.h in my legacy code.

```
#include "ssl\include\openssl\cmac.h"
```

(That's currently the only line I have in my code regarding OpenSSL).

During compilation (of the legacy code having the above include statement) now I get the following error:
"OpenSSL compile error: 'ENGINE' redeclared as different kind of symbol"

Yes, it is true, the the legacy code has a definition for 'ENGINE' but I'm not allowed to change it. So the question is now: How to keep both definitions? I think about sort of namespace or something, but I'm not that experienced on C? Please advice, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to separate the code, which uses different definitions of `ENGINE` in separate sourcefiles and only include the definitions of one of the two there. This should avoid conflicts.

Unfortunately, C doesn't know a construct like namespaces.

Comment: Actually it is already in different source files: One definition is in OpenSSL-sources and the other is in our internal legacy-sources. How should I separate this? Any idea, please?

Comment: You have to take care, that not both declarations are used in a single source-file (e.g. by including headers etc)

Answer (score 0):

> the legacy code has a definition for 'ENGINE' but I'm not allowed to
>   change it. So the question is now: How to keep both definitions?

Well, if you're not allowed to change the legacy code's definition, there's only one thing left (if you can't separate the compilation units): change OpenSSL's definition.

```
#define ENGINE  SSLENGINE
#include "ssl\include\openssl\cmac.h"
#undef  ENGINE
```

Note that you have to modify this approach if the legacy definition is a macro.